# pinterest link not working?

Tags: url, urlencode, pinterest

trying to create a pinterest link with javascript. It opens up pinterest, shows the correct images and description but when i click PIN IN it just refreshes and doesn't pin it.

[image: all looks ok but doesn't get pinned?!]

Creating a custom link and heres a URL created that i think should be working -

```
http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.modernactivity.co.uk%2Findependent_02%2F%3Fattachment_id%3D743&media=http%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.modernactivity.co.uk%2Findependent_02%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F06%2FBBC%20-%20MEAT-NEW%20WEBSITE%20TEST%204%3A3%20to%2016%3A9%20cropping-743-still-150x84.jpg&description=Independent%20Films%2C%20%E2%80%98Meat%E2%80%99&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.modernactivity.co.uk%2Findependent_02%2Fdirectors%2Fdaniel-levi%2Fshowreels%2Flive-action%2Fvideo%2F743%2F%23
```

Anyone know what might be wrong?

best, Dan.

Comment: same here. were you able to fix it?

Comment: nope. Why can't these guys just create a system that users good ol' vars in the URls?!

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. Let me start with a disclaimer. This answer might not even be right, but it did work for me. I had the same problem and my URL has lots of '+' in it.. which the URL encoded equivalent for a ' '. So, essentially pinterest seems to have a problem "pinning" them, although there seems to be no problem in rendering them... 
Your URI seems to have a lot of spaces too..

so, if the URI is in your control, you may

1. Create the uri after URLEncoding them
2. Make sure that spaces and such like dont appear on the URI.

Comment: Hey govi - dont i need the space for the title?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through my IIS Logs I noticed that Pinterest was redirecting users to my website without a leading http:// even if specified in the address, this seems to be causing the error for me.  Unsure how to fix this in IIS, but thought I'd throw you a clue I found.